# Where to find 64 bit version of chromedriver.exe for Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can anybody tell where I can find 64 bit version of chromedriver.exe? I tried it with 32bit also but it doesn't call main method.

Comment: What does "it doesnt call main method" mean? There isn't a 64bit version of ChromeDriver just like there isn't an available Chrome 64bit. There are 64bit developer builds of Chromium flying about but nothing that is released to the public by Google - so this is a really odd request. Please explain what it is that you are trying to achieve, and why you are having issues with it.

Comment: In addition to the above, here is the official issue on the Chromium tracker detailing exactly the same: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8606  ...there isn't a 64Bit version of it on Windows.

Comment: These comments are now outdated - there is now a supported 64-bit version of Chrome: 

* Go to chrome download page in windows https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/
* The platform defaults to 32-bit, even on a 64-bit windows install
* Select "Download Chrome for another platform", you will find the 64-bit windows build available, with no more mention of "beta"

Comment: Chrome will default to 64-bit on Windows from version 58. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 43):

There is no separate 64-bit version of Chromedriver. The version available at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads works on both 32 and 64-bit Windows, against either 32-or 64-bit Chrome.

This was confirmed in the Chromedriver issue tracker: 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1797#c1

> Yes, Chromedriver works on 64-bit Windows and against 64-bit Chrome successfully.

I came here while searching for the answer to if it works on 64-bit Chrome following the announcement that from version 58 Chrome will default to 64-bit on Windows provided certain conditions are met:
https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2017/05/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html

> In order to improve stability, performance, and security, users who are currently on 32-bit version of Chrome, and 64-bit Windows with 4GB or more of memory and auto-update enabled will be automatically migrated to 64-bit Chrome during this update. 32-bit Chrome will still be available via the Chrome download page.

Answer (score 6):

There is no separate chromedriver binary for Windows 64 bit. Chromedriver 32 bit binary works for both 32 as well as 64 bit versions of Windows. As of today, you can find the latest version of chromedriver Windows binary at https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/chromedriver_win32.zip

Comment: Is this true if Chrome itself is 64 bit, or do we need Chrome 32 bit...

Comment: @JohnPeters I wanted to know the same. Yes apparently it should work on both 32-bit and 64-bit Chorme. See my answer for more detail

Answer (score 1):

In the below mentioned link, ChromeDriver.exe for Windows 32 bit exist.

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/

It is working for me in Win7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 64bit runs both 32bit and 64bit applications. You want chromedriver 32bit for the 32bit version of chrome you're using.

The current release of chromedriver (v2.16) has been mentioned as running much smoother since it's older versions (there were a lot of issues before). This post mentions this and some of the slight differences between chromedriver and running the normal firefox driver:

http://seleniumsimplified.com/2015/07/recent-course-source-code-changes-for-webdriver-2-46-0/

What you mentioned about "doesn't call main method" is an odd remark. You may want to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but all the answers here are FALSE. There is x64 chrome driver version.

Please check this author's amazing work: https://github.com/macchrome/winchrome

All binaries are x64 and released as "Official Build".

Answer (score -2):

You will find newest version of the chromedriver here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html - there is a 64bit version for linux.

Comment: @pwolak- Thanks for it but if you let me know about the chromedriver64bit(Binary) for window8 then its helpful for me

Comment: Not answering the question (unfortunately, there seems to be no correct answer at this time)