# can not find x64 version chorome driver for selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i go to this link for install a chrome driver for selenium : [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers)

when i go to chrome i cant find x64 version for windows :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcQ1x.png)

and i get error because i have x64 Windows
how i do now ?
error when i run a selenium program :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFRr6.png)

i can not use selenium in 64 bit ?
or i can work to use selenium in 64 bit windows OS ?

Comment: I think this has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081507/where-to-find-64-bit-version-of-chromedriver-exe-for-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

yes you can work with Selenium in Windows 64 bit. I believe 90% of devs are using on x64.

[image]

```
win32 is pretty much compatible with x86 and x64.
```

[Official chrome driver link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no special install version for Selenium for Windows x64.
You can use the version of Windows x32 and it should work correctly.
Most Windows based machines are x64 today, we are all using Selenium x32 on them and it works just fine.

Comment: thank you but when i run a one python with selenium i get error for system type

Comment: What error do you have? I'm not sure it is about the Selenium installer version since there is no other, 64 but, version for Windows